# How to use overlayColor in TabBar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, tabbar

The Material Design [TabBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html) supports the named parameter [`overlayColor`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar/overlayColor.html) which is defined as `MaterialStateProperty<Color?>? overlayColor`.

I'm unable to use it and I couldn't find any examples of TabBar where it is used. Does anyone know how to use it?

Comment: overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Color(0xff077018))

Comment: This can be helpful: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialStateProperty-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet code to change `overlayColor`:

```dart
overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.transparent),
```